# How to determine the time at which a switch switches in Simulink?

Tags: time, logic, simulink

I have a switch in Simulink that switches once during a simulation. I would like to know at which time this occurs.

- I know that you can export the switching signal to your workspace. After the simulation, it is thus possible to easily extract the switching moment from this signal.
- I wondered whether there was an alternative to do this. Is there any block that can detect that the switch switches and save the corresponding switching time as a constant in the workspace?

Comment: If you know the switching signal then use it as the trigger in a triggered subsystem.  Feed a clock into the subsystem, and within the subsystem just feed the input to the output.  When the trigger occurs the value of the subsystem output will be the switching time.

Comment: @PhilGoddard - Thank you for your hint. This just generates an output signal that is the same or similar to the switching signal (see [Figure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L6ogd.png)). I would like to extract the switching time in Simulink and save it to a variable in the workspace.

Comment: Your question doesn't say that you want to dump it to the workspace. To do that, in the triggered subsystem, replace the outport with a To Workspace block.